# ERROR $ source .bashrc -ksh: .: .bashrc: cannot open [No such file or directory]

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, environment

my $HOME is set to /home/USERCODE

I created a script which should allow me to change my home (I don't have access nor can I use usermod due to my firm's policy)

my script creates all the .bashrc etc in a different folder
then adds the following in the /home/USERCODE/.bashrc

```
read -p "Home is set to $HOME. Would you like to change it to something else? [y/n]: " ANSWER
if [[ $ANSWER == "y" ]]; then
  read -p "Insert PATH : " ANSWER
  echo "export HOME=$ANSWER"    >> $HOME/.bashrc
  echo "export PREVHOME=$HOME"  >> $HOME/.bashrc
  echo "source $ANSWER/.bashrc" >> $HOME/.bashrc
  export HOME=$ANSWER 
  echo "Moving to $HOME"
  cd $ANSWER

  if [[ ! -f $HOME/.bashrc ]];then 
    echo "Creating .bashrc in $HOME ..."
    touch $HOME/.bashrc $HOME/.bash_profile $HOME/.bash_history $HOME/.bash_logout
  fi 

else
  echo "HOME var will remain $HOME"
fi
```

when I try to do source .bashrc in my new HOMEDIR I get :

```
$ source .bashrc
-ksh: .: .bashrc: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Comment: You're not putting any shell code in those files. The `touch` command simply creates empty files (assuming they don't already exist). Sourcing an empty file doesn't make any sense.

Comment:  doesn't need to make sense. that's not the problem. there is code in the bashrc. it's not all the code.

Comment: We must be missing some information here, since your code creates an empty file if one does not exist, and leaves the existing file in there.  So there always should be a .bashrc file in there...  Make sure your `$HOME` value == your new expected new HOMEDIR directory.  Are you sure you are in the expected directory?

Comment: I think the problem was that the old .bashrc file and the new .bashrc file were called the same . I changed the name of the new .bashrc file to something else .bashrc_USER and it works like a charm

Comment: @user06931912: You told me that the code you showed us is incomplete and you are actually putting bash shell code in the new *.bashrc*. Which means you were deliberately misleading the community. The content of the new *.bashrc* is important for this question. Your stated solution also doesn't make any sense. Renaming the file to *.bashrc__USER* means it won't be read by bash by default; you have to explicitly read it. And reading *.bashrc* should be idempotent. You've omitted a lot of important information about what you're doing.